# Usage of Flow tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the appropriate usage of the [flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow) tag?  Should there be any action done to it?

Looking at the questions for the [flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow) tag, it seems as though questions have used several different interpretations of the word:

- The mental state of flow, i.e. a productive trance
- Flow Control, or flow through code
- Development flow, or high-level production flow through business

All of these are very different definitions that have little relation to each other.  The tag itself currently has no description with which to determine original nor current intent.  How might we clean up or modify this tag?

Comment: Finished cleaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a start and changed the tag for about half of the questions from [flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow)  to [control-flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow) (where the latter IMHO fits better).

For the 6 remaining questions, I removed the "flow" tag from two since it seemed to be of minor importance. Then I added a description to the flow tag  ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology))) which fits well to the 4 remaining questions. So we are done here.

Comment: Nice work, Doc.